# Sorting adjacency hierarchy for simple output looping

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, hierarchy, adjacency-list

I'm pulling my hair out trying to avoid using multiple SQL queries. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

End result is a website navigation (ul/li) menu with nested links (dropdown menu) for some of the links.

The data comes from PDO as an array of objects. I believe my structure is referred to as an adjacency list, where each record has a parent ID which correlates to the id of the link under which it is nested, parent_id=0/NULL being top level. Every link also has a priority (a number by which to order them).

I require that the priority to only be relevant to the links on the same "level".

To output the html I really need the data in it's hierarchical order. I figured the uasort function could achieve this with a custom compare function, but I'm struggling to make it do anything comprehensible. Does uasort even make this possible?

Other avenues I thought might help were self joining SQL queries, or maybe looping through the array to build an object whereby "level2" links lived within the branch of it's parent (as you'd expect to see in an XML hierarchy).

Considering my current plans only require 2 levels and there won't be a million records to "sub-query" just tell me if you think I should concede and just use multiple queries.

Comment: it's because of this that MPTT was invented. https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: Thanks. I read about that, it has many benefits to the adjacency model, but seemed overkill for my needs (considering I don't require an arbitrary number of levels). But if it's the only way I'm going to have to consider it.

Comment: If you have only a few levels, don't worry at all about the queries. There will not be any performance impact at all. Specially if you cache the results.